# Block a key press event

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program in Python that prints "Hello" when the key "Space" is pressed, I just want to execute this code when this key is pressed and then block the event. For example, if there is a Notepad opened, I don't want it to add a white space when the "Space" key is pressed, I just want this key to execute the code and print "Hello" in the console.

This is my code, what can I use to block the event as described above?

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.space:
        print("hello")
        return False


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```